# How to rank a list with original order in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I want to make a ranking from a list and output it on original order.

This is my code so far:

```
     var data = new[] { 7.806468478, 7.806468478, 7.806468478, 7.173501754, 7.173501754, 7.173501754, 3.40877696, 3.40877696, 3.40877696, 
            4.097010736, 4.097010736, 4.097010736, 4.036494085, 4.036494085, 4.036494085, 38.94333318, 38.94333318, 38.94333318, 14.43588131, 14.43588131, 14.43588131 };


        var rankings = data.OrderByDescending(x => x)
               .GroupBy(x => x)
               .SelectMany((g, i) =>
                   g.Select(e => new { Col1 = e, Rank = i + 1 }))
               .ToList();
```

However, the result will be order it from descending:

[image: ranking]

What I want is to display by its original order.

e.g.: Rank = 3, Rank = 3, Rank = 3, Rank = 4, Rank = 4, Rank = 4, etc...

Thank You.

Comment: Could you please be more clear about your requirement? whats wrong with the current result

Comment: I want to make the ranking follow the original order, the ranking was okay. It is only the result display it by descending order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using what you have, one method would be to keep track of the original order and sort a second time (ugly and potentially slow):

```
var rankings = data.Select((x, i) => new {Item = x, Index = i})
       .OrderByDescending(x => x.Item)
       .GroupBy(x => x.Item)
       .SelectMany((g, i) =>
           g.Select(e => new { 
               Index = e.Index, 
               Item = new { Col1 = e.Item, Rank = i + 1 }
           }))
       .OrderBy(x => x.Index)
       .Select(x => x.Item)
       .ToList();
```

I would instead suggest creating a dictionary with your rankings and joining this back with your list:

```
var rankings = data.Distinct()
                   .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                   .Select((g, i) => new { Key = g, Rank = i + 1 })
                   .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Rank);

var output = data.Select(x => new { Col1 = x, Rank = rankings[x] })
                 .ToList();
```

As @AntonínLejsek kindly pointed out, replacing the above `GroupBy` call with `Distinct()` is the way to go.

Note `double`s are not a precise type and thus are really not a good candidate for values in a lookup table, nor would I recommend using `GroupBy`/`Distinct` with a floating-point value as a key. Be mindful of your precision and consider using an appropriate string conversion. In light of this, you may want to define an epsilon value and forgo LINQ's `GroupBy` entirely, opting instead to encapsulate each data point into a (non-anonymous) reference type, then loop through a sorted list and assign ranks. For example (disclaimer: untested):

```
class DataPoint
{
    decimal Value { get; set; }
    int Rank { get; set; }
}

var dataPointsPreservingOrder = data.Select(x => new DataPoint {Value = x}).ToList();

var sortedDescending = dataPointsPreservingOrder.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).ToList();

var epsilon = 1E-15; //use a value that makes sense here

int rank = 0;
double? currentValue = null;

foreach(var x in sortedDescending)
{
    if(currentValue == null || Math.Abs(x.Value - currentValue.Value) > epsilon) 
    {
        currentValue = x.Value;
        ++rank;
    }
    x.Rank = rank;
}
```

Comment: Personally like this version :)

Comment: `.ToString()` loses some precision as it displays only up to 15-16 significant digits by default, so I think it was better without it. The first example would have to end with something like `.OrderBy(x => x.Col1.Index).Select(x => new { Col1 = x.Col1.Item, x.Rank } )` in order to compile

Comment: @Slai Fair enough, and you actually have a point since we're already using equality comparison for `GroupBy`... let me see if I can think of something better.

Comment: Just use .Distinct() instead of GroupBy, it would be 2x faster and use less memory.

Answer (score 1):

From review of the data you will need to iterate twice over the result set.

The first iteration will be to capture the rankings as.

```
var sorted = data
    .OrderByDescending(x => x)
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select((g, i) => new { Col1 = g.First(), Rank = i + 1 })
    .ToList();
```

Now we have a ranking of highest to lowest with the correct rank value. Next we iterate the data again to find where the value exists in the overall ranks as:

```
var rankings = (from i in data
                let rank = sorted.First(x => x.Col1 == i)
                select new
                {
                    Col1 = i,
                    Rank = rank.Rank
                }).ToList();
```

This results in a ranked list in the original order of the data.

Answer (score 1):

A bit shorter:

```
var L = data.Distinct().ToList();      // because SortedSet<T> doesn't have BinarySearch :[
L.Sort();

var rankings = Array.ConvertAll(data, 
                                x => new { Col1 = x, Rank = L.Count - L.BinarySearch(x) });
```